# Error in Biztalk Expression Editor

Tags: c#-4.0, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2013

I am facing this error in Biztalk Expression Editor.
The command is trying to use is:
RequestMessage(EAISchemas.PropertySchema.TotalPrice)>10000.
Error encountered:
Operator '>' cannot be applied to operand of type System.string and System.int32.

Comment: Is your TotalPrice node in the EAISchemas.PropertySchema property schema of type integer? It might be xs:string

Comment: Nope..Its decimal.

Answer (score 0):

The distinguished property you reference that's part of RequestMessage is an Xpath expression. That's going to return the content of that node which is a string. So wrap it in conversion like System.Convert.toInt32().